# statify executables in chroot

Tags: chroot

I am trying to run arbitrary executables in a chroot. Unfortunately I have different version of the shared library dependencies of some of the executables in the chroot. Is it possible to reroute the loader for some executables, including the initial command, to use a different LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

There is statifier, but this seems to be a nonstandart tool (debian does not ship it) and so I am not allowed to use it.